# Laravel 7: Don't update resource

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm using update on my book by user but it's not update, when I put `title` of value. Doesn't work.

BookController:

```
public function update(Request $request, Book $book)
{

  if ($request->user()->id !== $book->user_id) {

    return response()->json(['error' => 'You can only edit your own books.'], 403);

  }
    $book->update($request->only(['title']));

    return new BookResource($book);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is `title` fillable in the Book model?

Comment: can you provide the route definition for that action?

Comment: @DigitalDrifter yes I have title in fillable

Comment: @lagbox I have using PUT of the route

Comment: The only method returns all of the key / value pairs that you request. Write to your log file  info('title:',[$request->only(['title'])]); and see what value you receive